# Automatically apply patch to Kubernetes service once created

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm, cicd

I have the following setup:

- A GitLab repository containing a simple Flask-based web service
- A locally deployed private K8s cluster with a configured GitLab agent and a group runner that the previously mentioned repository is using
- A GitLab CICD pipeline that creates a custom image with the service inside (port exposed using the `Dockerfile`), pushes it to the private registry and deploys it to the K8s cluster using Helm

The Helm configuration includes two things - a `deployment.yaml` (for the actual deployment) and a `service.yaml` for defining a service that relays requests to the deployed pod(s).

My cluster is running in a VM (Ubuntu Server 22.04, using `microk8s` for K8s) thus if I want to access the web service using my host's web browser I cannot simply use the cluster's internal network but expose the service to the VM's network that connects it to the host.

I always have to do

```
kubectl -n geo patch svc flask-test --patch="{\"spec\":{\"externalIPs\":[\"192.168.122.163\"]}}"
```

where the IP address is the one of the VM. After the patch is applied I have

[image: Kubernetes Dashboard view of the example service]

Only after that my web browser can actually interact with the service.

Is there a way to automatically apply a patch (either via `--patch` or `--patch-file`) to a service in Kubernetes once that service has been created? I though of adding the IP address to `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file where the deployment takes place since I can, after all, call `kubectl` to configure stuff just as I am calling `helm` to actually deploy and setup the service for my app. However this has many flaws including the fact that the IP address will probably change at some point, thus requiring touching every repository that is configured in a way that uses that IP address. That is why I would like to keep the cluster-related configuration to the cluster itself.

Comment: If you know that IP address up front, can you specify it in your Helm chart, instead of trying to modify the in-cluster address after the fact?  My impression is that `externalIPs` field is only informational, can you access the (LoadBalancer-type?) service without setting that field?

Comment: The IP is dynamic. At some point I will migrate the VM to our server (currently it runs on my laptop :D) in which case I will have a DNS but can also request a static IP address. Currently I have no load balancer setup (still reading and learning about that so there might be one that I don't know of :D). Since I run the VM without GUI I can only use `curl` and it does work with the cluster's IP address (here: 10.152.183.108). Outside of the VM (e.g. my host) this subnet is not visible hence the `externalIP` patch.

Comment: At the point where you run `helm install` or `helm upgrade`, do you know that IP address?  Passing it as a Helm value here seems easier.

Comment: I know it is easier. However this would make it hard-coded. Once the cluster's IP changes, this will break the deployment. I think I would just set the IP address in the same line by using `ip addr show` (with extra commands for bringing it into a form that is fits my needs).

Comment: I actually have a script for doing some automatic patching for a VPN tunnel (whenever it gets activated). I am retrieving the local IP address based on the adapter by calling `ip -f inet addr show enp1s0 | sed -En -e 's/.*inet ([0-9.]+).*/\1/p'`. After a possible migration I can still rename the virtual NIC to have the same name. :D

Comment: It wouldn't be especially hard-coded.  Where you `kubectl patch` now, you could `helm upgrade --set` the new value instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Helm to do this setup directly, without a separate `kubectl patch` step.  You can include the IP address in your manifest, with a value that is provided at deploy time.  For example:

```yaml
# templates/service.yaml
spec:
  externalIPs:
{{- with .Values.externalIP }}
    - {{ . }}
{{- else }}
    []
{{- end }}
```

Importantly, you do not need to include a specific setting in the `values.yaml` file for this.  If a `externalIP` value is set then it will be injected into the Service, but if not, an empty list will be used instead.

This means that you can provide a value at the command line, like

```yaml
helm install -n geo flask-test . \
  --set externalIP=192.168.122.163
```

But if that address ever changes, you can change the value here too

```yaml
helm upgrade -n geo flask-test . --reuse-values \
  --set externalIP=192.168.123.321
```

In this last example I've used `--reuse-values`, so Helm starts from the configuration that was used for the last installation and only updates the `externalIP` value.

Your CD system could do this too.  If it had some way of finding out what the IP address was, you could script running this `helm upgrade` command across every repository, without actually having to commit anything.  You could also combine this with some of the techniques you describe in the question and comments; if you can run a shell command then you can `--set externalIP=$(ip addr show ...)` for example.